# Override indentation settings with autocmd

Tags: indentation, autocmd

When editing Typescript neovim automatically sets `indentexpr=GetTypescriptIndent()`. I don't like the way it aligns to
an open brace instead of inserting a (soft) tab or two, but it doesn't seem to be configurable. I tried adding:

```
au FileType javascript,typescript setlocal cindent indentexpr&
```

to my init.vim but it hasn't made any difference; `indentexpr` is still set to `GetTypescriptIndent()` when I edit typescript files. How can I get my autocmd to override whatever typescript.vim does?

Answer (score 4):

To override settings, you need to use the `after` directory.

In this case, we need to know whether to use `after/indent` or `after/ftplugin`—use `:verbose set <options we care about>?` to find where they were last set, and pay attention to whether it was in the `ftplugin` or `indent` directory. We expect it to be `indent` in this case, but sometimes people do strange things.

Assuming we need to override an `indent` file, we place

```
setlocal indentexpr=
setlocal cindent
```

In `~/.vim/after/indent/javascript.vim` (ditto for `typescript`).

Don’t forget to read about `b:undo_ftplugin` and `b:undo_indent`—they will need to be set properly.

To quote from `:h undo_indent`:

```
When the user does ":setfiletype xyz" the effect of the previous filetype
should be undone.  Set the b:undo_ftplugin variable to the commands that will
undo the settings in your filetype plugin.
...
For undoing the effect of an indent script, the b:undo_indent variable should
be set accordingly.
```

In this case, we'll need to append

```
'setlocal indentexpr< cindent<'
```

to `b:undo_indent`:

```
let b:undo_indent = get(b:, 'undo_indent', '')
if !empty(b:undo_indent)
  let b:undo_indent .= '|'
endif
let b:undo_indent .= 'setlocal indentexpr< cindent<'
```

Comment: It *should* be `indent`, right? I mean, that's the point of `filetype indent on`, you want to be able to enable/disable indentation plug-ins on their own... (Maybe you could/should assume that in your answer?)

Comment: @filbranden yes, but sometimes people do wacky things (I wouldnt expect it from the core vimruntime, but if its a plugin or something you never really know). Ill make a note though

Comment: In typescript's particular case, yeah, an indent file, as expected: https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim/blob/master/indent/typescript.vim

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. I'm not sure how I should use `b:undo_indent`, but I don't think it will matter for me anyway.

Comment: @realh does my edit make `undo_indent` clearer?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, that's much clearer, thanks. The line containing `get` is still mysterious to me though. Apparently `b:` can be used as a `List`. OK... But I don't understand why the line is necessary at all.

Comment: @realh `b:` is a dictionary. The variable may or may not have been previously set, so we grab the old value or make it empty as a « default ». That way further accesses dont fail